# Image Dimension Size in Denoising Image using CNN

Tags: image, machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a set of synthetically noisy images. Example is shown below:

[image]

I have also their corresponding clean text images as my ground truth data. Example below:

[image]

The dimension size of the two images is  `4918 x 5856`. Is it an appropriate size for training my Convolutional Neural Network that will perform image denoising. If no, what shall I do? Resize or crop? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This resolution really is overkill. You can start off with 1/64 of the size ~(600,750), which is already pretty big.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem recently as well. I learned that you need to crop the image into patches, each of about 500x500. Then you need to denoise each patch and put it all together. This usually gets the most accurate results. Let me know if you need anything else!